# algorithm to find the root of a real-valued function $f$

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I see in a book the following algorithm to find the root of a real-valued function $f$

$$ \theta_{n+1} = \theta_{n} + \epsilon f(\theta_n); \epsilon >0 $$
 with the condition that the initial point will be sufficiently close the solution. What is the proof ?

Answer (score 3):

This will tend to converge on roots where $f'$ is negative. $\Delta \theta$ in the vicinity will point toward the zero on either side. This has loosely similar behaviour to gradient descent algorithms, but those target minima rather than zeroes.

The algorithm will diverge from roots where $f'$ is positive. $\Delta \theta$ will point away from such a root.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MarkFantini, this is just as much an answer as the other one posted here, given the context.

Answer (score 2):

That does not work without more assumptions on $f$. Let's look at $f(x) = x$. Then the recursion reads
$$ \theta_{n+1} = \theta_n + \epsilon \cdot \theta_n = (1+\epsilon)\theta_n $$
So $\theta_n = (1+\epsilon)^n \theta_0$, which diverges for any $\theta_0 \ne 0$.